How to do simulation of all/most pending transactions?
everybody.  I have a task to search in mempool for transactions like "swap tokens for eth" or any other type where a wallet sells tokens and its transaction can affect token reserves. There are many tokens and their contract adresses are stored in an array.
I couldn't find how to filter pending transactions for my task, without high load for CPU. The only option I came up with is to filter out all transactions that have value zero (because 98% of "swap tokens for eth" have value 0.
And so, now my code can filter out most of the transactions that I definitely don't need. But now I need to simulate the ones with value == 0. I found alchemy api to simulate transactions, but it requires filling in the "From" field. But go-ethereum/geth method "SubscribeFullPendingTransactions", does not provide a way to know who sent the transaction. It is possible to find out who sent it using other tools, but it requires many lines of code with type conversions, very many. I found this method unworkable because transactions with value == 0 are 11-14 per second on average.
And I need to find out information about how many tokens a wallet wants to sell before its transaction is executed.
I've been thinking for many days now, and I can't figure out how to solve my problem. If you know how I can solve it, please help me.

Let me know if my answer helps.

Let's split it into smaller tasks to tackle the problem.


In reality, a properly implemented node should provide you with the from address as well, [as per the Ethereum transaction specification](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/#whats-a-transaction).

A submitted transaction includes the following information:

from – the address of the sender, that will be signing the
transaction. This will be an externally-owned account as contract
accounts cannot send transactions.
to – the receiving address (if an externally-owned account, the
transaction will transfer value. If a contract account, the
transaction will execute the contract code)
signature – the identifier
of the sender. This is generated when the sender's private key signs
the transaction and confirms the sender has authorized this
transaction
nonce - a sequentially incrementing counter which
indicates the transaction number from the account
value - amount of ETH to transfer from sender to recipient (denominated in WEI, where
1ETH equals 1e+18wei)
input data – optional field to include arbitrary
data
gasLimit – the maximum amount of gas units that can be consumed
by the transaction. The EVM specifies the units of gas required by
each computational step
maxPriorityFeePerGas the maximum price of
the consumed gas to be included as a tip to the validator
maxFeePerGas
the maximum fee per unit of gas willing to be paid for the transaction (inclusive of baseFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas)


And the go-ethereum's transaction object looks this way:
// Transaction is an Ethereum transaction.
type Transaction struct {
    inner TxData    // Consensus contents of a transaction
    time  time.Time // Time first seen locally (spam avoidance)

    // caches
    hash atomic.Pointer[common.Hash]
    size atomic.Uint64
    from atomic.Pointer[sigCache] // the FROM address
}

For instance, slightly modifying the go-ethereum's test suite, we can see that the from address was logged by the event listener accumulator too, by slightly modifying the go-ethereum/build/ci.go file's doTest function:
// Running The Tests
//
// "tests" also includes static analysis tools such as vet.

func doTest(cmdline []string) {
    var (
        dlgo     = flag.Bool("dlgo", false, "Download Go and build with it")
        arch     = flag.String("arch", "", "Run tests for given architecture")
        cc       = flag.String("cc", "", "Sets C compiler binary")
        coverage = flag.Bool("coverage", false, "Whether to record code coverage")
        verbose  = flag.Bool("v", true, "Whether to log verbosely")
        race     = flag.Bool("race", false, "Execute the race detector")
        short    = flag.Bool("short", false, "Pass the 'short'-flag to go test")
        cachedir = flag.String("cachedir", "./build/cache", "directory for caching downloads")
    )
    flag.CommandLine.Parse(cmdline)

    // Get test fixtures.
    csdb := build.MustLoadChecksums("build/checksums.txt")
    downloadSpecTestFixtures(csdb, *cachedir)

    // Configure the toolchain.
    tc := build.GoToolchain{GOARCH: *arch, CC: *cc}
    if *dlgo {
        tc.Root = build.DownloadGo(csdb)
    }
    gotest := tc.Go("test")

    // CI needs a bit more time for the statetests (default 10m).
    gotest.Args = append(gotest.Args, "-timeout=20m")

    // Enable CKZG backend in CI.
    gotest.Args = append(gotest.Args, "-tags=ckzg")

    // Enable integration-tests
    gotest.Args = append(gotest.Args, "-tags=integrationtests")

    // Test a single package at a time. CI builders are slow
    // and some tests run into timeouts under load.
    gotest.Args = append(gotest.Args, "-p", "1")
    if *coverage {
        gotest.Args = append(gotest.Args, "-covermode=atomic", "-cover")
    }
    if *verbose {
        gotest.Args = append(gotest.Args, "-v")
    }
    if *race {
        gotest.Args = append(gotest.Args, "-race")
    }
    if *short {
        gotest.Args = append(gotest.Args, "-short")
    }

    packages := []string{"./ethclient/gethclient"} // <----- just specifying a particular test directory to test the SubscribeFullPendingTransactions function in action
    if len(flag.CommandLine.Args()) > 0 {
        packages = flag.CommandLine.Args()
    }
    gotest.Args = append(gotest.Args, packages...)
    build.MustRun(gotest)
}

And running the following slightly modified ethclient/gethclient/gethclient_test.go test with make test:
func testSubscribeFullPendingTransactions(t *testing.T, client *rpc.Client) {
    ec := New(client)
    ethcl := ethclient.NewClient(client)
    // Subscribe to Transactions
    ch := make(chan *types.Transaction)
    ec.SubscribeFullPendingTransactions(context.Background(), ch)
    // Send a transaction
    chainID, err := ethcl.ChainID(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Create transaction
    tx := types.NewTransaction(1, common.Address{1}, big.NewInt(1), 22000, big.NewInt(1), nil)
    signer := types.LatestSignerForChainID(chainID)
    signature, err := crypto.Sign(signer.Hash(tx).Bytes(), testKey)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    signedTx, err := tx.WithSignature(signer, signature)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Send transaction
    err = ethcl.SendTransaction(context.Background(), signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Check that the transaction was sent over the channel
    tx = <-ch
    if tx.Hash() != signedTx.Hash() {
        t.Fatalf("Invalid tx hash received, got %v, want %v", tx.Hash(), signedTx.Hash())
    }

    fromAddress, err := types.Sender(types.LatestSignerForChainID(tx.ChainId()), tx)

    fmt.Printf("The sender of the transaction indeed is: %s\n", fromAddress)
}

For fmt.Printf to work properly, please also make sure that you add the required import ("fmt") among the other imports at the top of the file gethclient_test.go file.

Finally, you'll see the address from getting logged:
...
=== RUN   TestGethClient/TestSubscribePendingTxs
The sender of the transaction indeed is: 0x71562b71999873DB5b286dF957af199Ec94617F7
=== RUN   TestGethClient/TestCallContract
=== RUN   TestGethClient/TestCallContractWithBlockOverrides
... (clipped contents)

Voilà!



By the way, the legacy transaction has the following structure:
// LegacyTx is the transaction data of the original Ethereum transactions.
type LegacyTx struct {
    Nonce    uint64          // nonce of sender account
    GasPrice *big.Int        // wei per gas
    Gas      uint64          // gas limit
    To       *common.Address `rlp:"nil"` // nil means contract creation
    Value    *big.Int        // wei amount
    Data     []byte          // contract invocation input data
    V, R, S  *big.Int        // signature values
}

The legacy LegacyTx type is also why it's often confused right now like there's no from field in the Transaction type, whereas that property actually exists there in type Transaction right now.




Finally, simulating the transaction is more complex.
But you can use tools like Alchemy or this package: https://github.com/EnsoFinance/temper. (Dislaimer: I'm not a contributor nor a creator of this package, but it looks very interesting at the quick glance!)
If approached with a service like the Alchemy Simulation API, you can get exactly precise results from a simulation in any block:

Alternatively, you can use https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/eth_call by Quicknode.
But I believe that you'll need to make an external API request, or make a direct request to the Ethereum (or L2) RPC, calling eth_call to simulate a transaction without actually submitting it to the blockchain.
Still, all of these require some sort of external API/RPC integration.



Hope it helps! Ping me in the comments if you need something else.

(Edited)
Nethermind's node RPC API supports a simulation eth_call and eth_callMany methods.
Maybe you can try simulating a transaction by referring to the Nethermind node's methods?

E.g.:
curl localhost:8545 \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "id": 0,
      "method": "trace_call",
      "params": [call, traceTypes, blockParameter]
    }'

Where the call is an object:

address: string (address)
blobVersionedHashes: array of string (hex data)
blockHash: string (hash)
blockNumber: string (hex integer)
chainId: string (hex integer)
data: string (hex data)
from: string (address)
gas: string (hex integer)
gasPrice: string (hex integer)
hash: string (hash)
input: string (hex data)
isSystemTx: boolean
maxFeePerBlobGas: string (hex integer)
maxFeePerGas: string (hex integer)
maxPriorityFeePerGas: string (hex integer)
mint: string (hex integer)
nonce: string (hex integer)
r: string (hex integer)
s: string (hex integer)
sourceHash: string (hash)
to: string (address)
transactionIndex: string (hex integer)
type: integer
v: string (hex integer)
value: string (hex integer)
blockParameter: string (block number or hash or either of earliest, finalized, latest, pending, or safe)

**You can populate the object with corresponding data using SubscribeFullPendingTransactions' callbacks, and the decoded from field.

Thank you for your reply! I guess it's my fault for not notifying here that I've solved my problem.
I get ‘from’ using this function
func GetFrom(tx *types.Transaction) (string, error) {
from, err := types.Sender(types.LatestSignerForChainID(tx.ChainId()), tx)
return from.String(), err
}
And use the response in a query to the alchemy api .
Using a package rather than third party services would probably be better. But this package is written in Rust, but I don't know it.

Aaah, great you've found the solution!!! Glad my answer was helpful, thank you @solo11

Oh, turns out I was wrong. I won't be able to solve my problem because Alchemi api happens to provide daily limits, which are not written anywhere. A plan without limits is very expensive ;//

At least the Step №1 is now clear: extracting the from address is possible from a transaction WS receipt listening to SubscribeFullPendingTransactions. Yeah, Alchemy is powerful, yet their prices are quite pesky. Maybe you can use the NPM package then? (https://github.com/EnsoFinance/temper) It requires a local/remote RPC node  running, these are available for free, or at low costs plans can be purchased from Ankr. Probably the time efficiency will be much weaker though... @solo11

I have nethermind node, it is installed on my server. I don't understand how I can interact with this package, it is written in Rust.

Oh, now I see that this package is running as a server.

this package doesn't work =(

I'd like to help you, @solo11. First of all, why do you need to specifically simulate the transactions? There could be other ways to estimating how the reserves will be affected without similating the transaction practically.

temper might now work for you because it doesn't support Nethermind IPCs yet.

Can you try it with Nethermind node's trace_call RPC call? See the screenshot above in my updated answer. @solo11

I tried trace_call, that's not what I need.
